# Beamer presentation with Pandoc and Markdown - Headers don't work properly

Tags: markdown, pandoc, beamer

I'm trying to show how different headers are shown in markdown. This is part of the `pres.md`:

```
# Headers

# H1
## H2
### H3
#### H4
##### H5
###### H6
```

And I compile it using this command:

```
pandoc pres.md -t beamer -o pres.pdf
```

But the result is this:

[image: headers]

There are two problems here.

1- `# H1` is considered as the page header.

2- All other headers are the same size.

I understand why the first problem happens, because *Pandoc* treats h1 headers as the header of the page. And I can change that by changing the implicit `--slide-level=1` of `Pandoc` command. But changing that option to any other value (between 1 and 6) will result in `Pandoc` treating that header as the the page header, which is not what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to have all the headers appear as they would on, for example, GitHub, while having `# H1` headers taken as page header (`--slide-level=1`) for the rest of the presentation.

The desired output is something like this, for a single slide of the presentation:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Beamer is a special case that does not have so many different hierarchy levels. The idea is that for presentations only a couple of levels should be used, everything else will confuse the audience. If you want to show how different headers are shown, use a documentclass that actually supports this many levels

Comment: @samcarter That's fair, but why do different headers all have the same size?

Comment: Can you show the intermediate .tex file?

Comment: @samcarter How can I do that? I only have a `.md` file that I convert, using Pandoc, to `.pdf`.

Comment: see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html "To debug the PDF creation, it can be useful to look at the intermediate representation: instead of -o test.pdf, use for example -s -o test.tex to output the generated LaTeX. You can then test it with pdflatex test.tex."

Comment: slide shows are indeed quite special, see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#producing-slide-shows-with-pandoc